# Apache 403 (Forbidden) on subdirectory on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, .htaccess, windows-8

So yesterday i installed Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3, and MySQL on my Windows 8 Machine.  I am using the same vhost / .htaccess files on both but it works on my Mac and not Windows.  Basically When i go to "mysite.dev" it renders the homepage of the site, but once i go to any page, such as "mysite.dev/about/" i get a 403 Forbidden Error.

I have verified that Apache runs as "System" on my computer and then made sure all permissions from the site folder to root are set to Full Access for the user/group System.

I've tried many many things and cant figure this out and its rather annoying.  Anyways i've posted below all of the settings / logs.  Thanks in advanced.

**vhosts:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin MyEmail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Sites/onmytv"
    ServerName onmytv.dev
    ServerAlias www.onmytv.dev

    <Directory "C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Sites/onmytv">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Error displayed on webpage:**

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Sites/onmytv/index.php/about/ on this server.
```

**error.log**

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20023)The given path was above the root path: Cannot map GET /about/ HTTP/1.1 to file
```

**access.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2012:17:57:17 -0400] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 403 256
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]     Can you try this at your last rewrite line

Comment: Is mod_rewrite even compiled?

Comment: Yes Mod_rewrite is on :)

Comment: Svetlio: That was it :)  403 no longer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to change the following the in .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks @Svetlio for that useful comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin MyEmail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Sites/onmytv"
    ServerName onmytv.dev
    ServerAlias www.onmytv.dev

    <Directory "C:/Users/Michael/Dropbox/Sites/onmytv">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```