# Localhost throwing 403 Forbidden Error Apache Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, apache, docker-compose

So I have just moved work computers from my Windows Surfacebook to a Thinkpad provided by my company. I have been going through our laravel setup to get our project running on our environment. However, when I proceed to localhost:8888, I get the following: 
    `Forbidden
    You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

So I've been trying to figure out why this is happening. I went through the exact process I alwasy have for windows: Installed Docker Desktop, Install chocolatey, install php via composer, pull the code from github into a src folder, created the apache php & mongodb containers with docker-compose up. Yet I still am getting 403 Forbidden error.

I have tried messing with dependencies with `composer update`, checked my .htaccess file which I've never touched but has worked for my other projects on my other computer, same .env file from my other computer, etc. Is it perhaps because its a brand new computer? I had to add my user into the group of users to use docker, perhaps that's blocking it? Do I need to grant permissions on this new computer? All these files should be fine, that's why I'm very confused.

Anything helps, please let me know if there's another file you would like to see code of!

.htaccess file: 

    
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:8LWCAd54wFeq8GUwikoyfKuaKlaUKS/BZwsClqEuAx4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=192.168.99.100
DB_PORT=9999
DB_DATABASE=........Private
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=projecttracker@mg.ceg.mn
MAIL_FROM_NAME="CEG Project Tracker"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.ceg.mn
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
MAILGUN_SECRET=..............Private
```

my index.php file:

````
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);```
````

Comment: The apache user have access?

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo What do you mean by the apache user having access? Is there somewhere that grants permission to use the apache server? I have never dealt with that in the past I don't think

Comment: The user running the apache server service must have access to the website directory.

Comment: Maybe, this is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203608/apache-403-forbidden-on-subdirectory-on-windows